# What is a good way to edit a record in a database and preserve the former record

Tags: database-design, data-binding, edit, database-schema

I'm developing an application that doesn't allow delete. It allows edit, but the old records must be preserved. I'm not sure the best method to implement this, but here are my thoughts.

I intend to implement this by creating a similar table to the one that contains the original record. Example `tableA` contains the original record, then `tableA1` contains the edited version or vice versa. When the need for edit arises, I can move the edited record from `tableA` to the second table `tableA1` and add a link that can retrieve the original record. Is this a good method, or is there a better method?

Comment: What will be the usage pattern of the old records vs. the new records?

Comment: @DrC a link to the old records will always appear beside the current record. The edit history must be kept.

Comment: How often do you expect users to look at old records?  If a record has been edited 10 times, I assume they can go back through all 10 versions?

Comment: @DrC yes, all the changes must be preserved, all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I can think of is to have a lookup table and a data table

```
**DataTable**
-DataID
-ColumnA
-ColumnB
-ColumnC
-...

**LookupTable**
-RecordID (This is the important ID for you)
-DataID (Key From DataTable)
-Modified DateTime (or could be revisionID or something like that to allow for order of change)
```

I think it's pretty self-explanatory from here, to get a new record, you select the most recenlty modfied date (or highest revision number) of the record ID you want, and join it with the dataTable

Answer (score 1):

```
table myText
id  text  date  author  extraInfo

table oldText
id  text  date
```

`oldText.id` being a foreign key referencing `myText.id`

Then create a trigger on update to `myValues` which will insert into `myOldValues`.

It's possible this isn't normalized or the best design. An alternative would be to have no "text/date" info in `myText` and always use a join with `myOldText`. Then you wouldn't need a trigger, you'd just search for the newest entry in `oldText` (which you'd rename btw) with corresponding `id`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the data warehouse technique of slowly changing dimensions, where all your data is kept in the same table.

Basically you have your normal columns and a VERSION, KEY, CURRENT and REC_STATUS column. When the user edits a record you make a copy of the record back into the table, increment the VERSION and set the original REC_STATUS to 'Deleted' and the newly inserted record to 'UPDATE' or 'INSERT'

The CURRENT column is set to N for all records except the latest version, which allows for simple SELECTS, and you also have the option to look at the history.  (There are other columns like REC_START_DATE and REC_END_DATE as well).
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension